# Flutter slider overlay color

Tags: flutter, slider

I have changed the color of the overlay but it still does not take effect as it maintains the color of the thumbShape instead.

```
 SliderTheme(
          data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
            activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
            overlayShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 25.0),
            overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            value: height.toDouble(),
            min: 122.0,
            max: 220.0,
            inactiveColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
            onChanged: (double newValue) {
              setState(() {
                height = newValue.round();
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `overlayShape`.

I think it was overriding the color I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inactive and active track color in your theme to avoid this problem.

```
SliderTheme(
                data: SliderThemeData(
                  thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                    enabledThumbRadius: 15,
                  ),
                  overlayColor: Color(0x29eb1555),
                  activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xff8d8e98),
                  thumbColor: Color(0xffeb1555),
                ),
                child: Slider(
                  value: height.toDouble(),
                  min: 120,
                  max: 220,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      height = value.round();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You used `RoundSliderThumbShape` for both `thumbShape` and `overlayShape`. Instead, use `RoundSliderOverlayShape` for `overlayShape` property, and you are good to go.

```
data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
            activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
            overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 25.0), // Change in here
            overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
          ),
```